# Custom view vs. fragment for supplementary UI sections

Tags: android, view, fragment

I'm making an app that will allow a user to make and edit a picture (think MS Paint like).  I want there to be a "formatting window" type control which contains a set of tools the user can pick from to edit the picture.  For example, it could contain buttons for inserting text, drawing lines, erasing content, etc.  The flow would be: user presses the action bar icon for the formatting window, the formatting window opens, and the user presses the button for the associated tool.

I'm curious how I should be handling this type of control for different form factors.  It's very simple UI wise - a relative layout view group with a set of buttons lined up in rows.  But if I wanted to have it appear at the bottom of the screen on phones (animating up from beneath the screen when the action bar button associated with showing the window is pressed), and at the top right corner of the screen in tablets (animating from the right), how would I best do that?  Do I just setup my two phone and tablet layouts to contain the custom formatting window view in different positions?  Should the formatting window be a fragment?  Help!

Comment: I forgot to add in that I do not want a separate activity for the formatting window - it should be able to appear on screen along/partially overlapping the image being edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that either approach would work, but a custom view sounds easier to me. Either way, you'll need separate layout files for phone vs tablet, since you need to place the view or fragment in a different location.

The thing that would probably make a difference here is how your backing data is being stored. Meaning, what stores the user's choice for formatting controls? My immediate thought would be to use a custom view for the formatting window and allow the activity to set a listener to be notified when the formatting choices change.

Comment: Hey Drew, I agree with your comments here.  I will definitely need a phone and tablet layout.  My idea about "what stores the user's choice" is also the same you had.  When a button/formatting option is selected, the activity holds onto that information through a callback from the view.